# Can't delete or override files in production

Tags: laravel

On my local, I can store and delete files just fine.

```
if ($subchan->styles_path != null) {
    Storage::disk('public')->delete($filePath.'/'.$filename);
}               
    
Storage::disk('public')->put($filePath.'/'.$filename, $text);
```

Both the `put` and `delete` work just fine. I don't even need the `delete` here, since the `put` just replaces the old file with the new file.

However, in production, I can only ever upload a file, not delete. Deleting doesn't work, and trying to upload a new file to replace the old one won't work. So I'm essentially stuck on the first file I uploaded.

There are no errors in the error log, either.

Why is this happening?

**EDIT**

This is probably that weirdest production bug I've ever encountered. It seems that these files are being cached. So it DOES replace the files with a new one, but the changes only show after a few hours it seems.

I use laravel octane. Could this be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this `$subchan->styles_path != null` is returning null in production.

Comment: It isn't. And like I stated in the post, even if the delete function didn't work, the put SHOULD override the original file since it's the same filename. I checked with SSH and no duplicate files are being created.